# Parse.com cloudcode never entering success/error

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, cloud

I have this code running in my parse cloud, and when I call it form my app, it never enters the  success or error statement. Probably because the .save does not work?

Any help is much appreciated :)

This is how I call the cloud function :

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"addFeeling"
                   withParameters:@{@"userId"           : [[PFUser currentUser]objectId],
                                    @"relationShipId"   : _friendship.objectId,
                                    @"tagId"            : [NSNumber numberWithInt:tag],
                                    @"reason"           : @"Hardcoded HomeView(409)",
                                    @"value"            : [NSNumber numberWithInt:value]}
                            block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
                                if (!error) {
                                    DLog(@"results :%@", result);
                                }
                                else{
                                    DLog(@"Error : %@", error);
                                }
                            }];
```

And this is the cloud fucntion itself:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("addFeeling", function(request, response) {
    var userId         = request.params.userId;
    var relationShipId = request.params.friendshipId;
    var tagId          = request.params.tagId;
    var reason         = request.params.reason;
    var value          = request.params.value;

    var Feels = Parse.Object.extend("Feels");
    var feeling = new Feels();
    feeling.set("id_friendship", relationShipId);
    feeling.set("value", value);
    feeling.set("tag", tagId);
    feeling.set("reason", reason);
    feeling.save({
        success: function () {
            var query = new Parse.Query("Feels");
            query.equalTo("id_friendship", relationShipId);
            query.find({
                success: function(results) {
                    if(results.length > 0)
                    {
                        result = results[0];
                        if(result.get("userFrom") == userId)
                            result.set("scoreTo"  , result.get("scoreTo") + value);
                        else
                            result.set("scoreFrom", result.get("scoreFrom") + value);
                        result.save();
                    }
                }
            });
            console.log("Save ok");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            response.error(error);
            console.log("Save ko");
        }
    });
});
```

This is probably really simple but I'm just not used to JS at all.

The error i get is code:141, enver entering success/error.

Answer (score 0):

When your function is finished with doing what you intend it to do, you are supposed to call either `response.success()` or `response.error()` to indicate that you are done.

You are already doing it for the case there is an error, but not when actually processing the result of your query.